# USB AutoRun: 'Open In Browser' Option never appears

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, usb, autorun

I am attempting to make our webpage open when someone plugs in our USB device.

**My Problem:** When we plug in the USB device the autorun dialog appears but there is never an option to open/run the webpage we have specified. See below pic of the dialog we see. Isn't there meant to be an option that says something like "Open in Internet Explorer" or etc.?

[image]

What we are hoping to achieve is to have another option below 'Use this drive for backup' that says something like *'Open in Web Browser'* or something that will ultimately open our webpage when the users decides to.

Heres our code that is inside the file autorun.inf which is placed on the USB device:

```
[autorun]
shellexecute=http://exds-test.epicservices.com.au/V10InstallationInfo.aspx
action=Open Website
label=EXDS USB Drive
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this link, this will not work on modern OS versions
http://www.flashbay.com/services/usb-autorun

You've got to use a "helper" application.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a helper application that I can use other than Firefox portable?

Comment: You can try something like this... but i haven't used it myself. http://download.cnet.com/MyPendrive/3000-2094_4-10589782.html?tag=api